# FQDN's in crypto maps and AAA servers possible with dynamic DNS resolution? Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, aaa

Can I use FQDN's in crypto maps when setting a peer (where I'd normally use an IP), and can I use FQDN's when defining an LDAP Server or any other AAA Server in a server group?  In both cases the FQDN's would have to be resolved by calls to an external DNS server (FQDN objects).

If the answer is yes, please provide a quick example of how to do that.
I already know how to use FQDN's in ACL's, setup external DNS and validate the ASA is resolving those properly.

Comment: AL, are you asking whether it's possible to have the ASA [re-resolve](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/66011/asa-using-hostnames-dns-access-lists-configuration-steps-caveats-and-troubleshooting) the FQDN every so often (like they do for dynamic ACLs)?.  It would help if you gave a concrete example of where the FQDN is defined, and the circumstances that you want the ASA to check.

Comment: Hey Mike, yes that's exactly what I'm talking about.  In these cases - we have a vendor given url, that we must use in a AAA-server config and also for a peer IP in a crypto map for a L2L IPsec tunnel.  Not sure how much more to put in the question to get that across.

Comment: Ok, if you can be specific about the TTL on the DNS record, it would help.  Check the TTL with `nslookup` (Windows) or `dig` (Linux / Windows)

Comment: The particular record I'd need to resolve has a TTL of 58 seconds, so we'd need to resolve the names used in these cases every 58s or less ideally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to [the Cisco documentation (v8.4)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/98634-asa-ldap-group-pol.html#cli), you can use a hostname most places you use an IP address.

Here's an example lifted from the documentation:

```
ne-asa(config)#aaa-server LDAP_SRV_GRP (inside) host myserver.networkegineering.stackexchage.com
ne-asa(config-aaa-server-host)#ldap-attribute-map ne-MAP
```

Comment: I should have revised the question.  FQDN that's dynamically resolved via outside DNS.  I can map things statically no problem, I was referring to FQDN objects.  Any thoughts there?

Comment: @AL I haven't actually tried it, but according to the docs, ASA doesn't care what interface the DNS server is on.  See http://goo.gl/3zr9cB

Comment: Hey Ron, yeah I currently use external DNS in a few ACL entries, so configuring external DNS isn't the issue.  The problem is that when you use FQDN's you have to make a network object containing them, and I'm not sure if that network-object type can be used in crypto maps or in aaa-server configs.

Comment: @AL As I said, I don't have a spare ASA to test.  It probably would be fastest just to try it.

Comment: I was finally able to get a test going, and can confirm your suggestion!  as long as the interface you set in the aaa-server has a matching dns-lookup INTNAME and a name-server on the same interface that can resolve your hostname you're good.  It worked for crypto maps too.  Good stuff, thanks for the help!